# Execute task after another task

Tags: gradle

I have created a separate source set which depends on main source set:

```
sourceSets {
   customSrc {
      output.classesDir = main.output.classesDir
      output.resourcesDir = main.output.resourcesDir
      compileClasspath += main.output
   }
}
```

now I want to compile this source set whenever main source set compiles, so when `gradle compile` is invoked my source set is also compiled.

I can simply add dependency to `build` task like that:

```
build.dependsOn customSrcClasses
```

but that is unreliable, someone can call just `classes` task and custom source set will not compile.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: It seems that what can be useful is `finalizedBy`. Since dependencies between `compile*` and `build` and `classes` are already established what you need is to _attach_ your task at the same point in DAG. However, with `finalizedBy` additional sources will be compiled always when java sources are compiled.

Comment: @Opal, yep currently I use `finalizedBy`, but it has a bit different meaning, it is like `finally`, but I do not need `finally` functionality, so question is still open :)